# How do I take already calculated totals that are in a loop and add them together?

Tags: python-2.7

I created this program in Python 2.7.3
I did this in my Computer Science class.  He assigned it in two parts.  For the first part we had to create a program to calculate a monthly cell phone bill for five customers.  The user inputs the number of texts, minutes, and data used.  Additionaly, there are overage fees.  $10 for every GB of data over the limit, $.4, per minute over the limit, and $.2 per text sent over the limit.  500 is the limit amount of text messages, 750 is the limit amount of minutes, and 2 GB is the limit amount of data for the plan.

For part 2 of the assignment.  I have to calculate the total tax collected, total charges (each customer bill added together), total goverment fees collected, total customers who had overages etc.

Right now all I want help on is adding the customer bills all together.  As I said earlier,   when you run the program it prints the Total bill for 5 customers.  I don't know how to assign those seperate totals to a variable, add them together, and then eventually print them as one big variable.

```
TotalBill = 0    
monthly_charge = 69.99
data_plan = 30
minute = 0
tax = 1.08
govfees = 9.12
Finaltext = 0
Finalminute = 0
Finaldata = 0
Finaltax = 0
TotalCust_ovrtext = 0
TotalCust_ovrminute = 0
TotalCust_ovrdata = 0
TotalCharges = 0

for i in range (1,6):
    print "Calculate your cell phone bill for this month"

    text = input ("Enter texts sent/received ")

    minute = input ("Enter minute's used ")

    data = input ("Enter Data used ")
    if data > 2:
        data = (data-2)*10
        TotalCust_ovrdata = TotalCust_ovrdata + 1        
    elif data <=2:
        data = 0
    if minute > 750:
        minute = (minute-750)*.4
        TotalCust_ovrminute = TotalCust_ovrminute + 1
    elif minute <=750:
        minute = 0
    if text > 500:
        text = (text-500)*.2
        TotalCust_ovrtext = TotalCust_ovrtext + 1
    elif text <=500:
        text = 0

    TotalBill = ((monthly_charge + data_plan + text + minute + data) * (tax)) + govfees 
    print ("Your Total Bill is... " + str(round(TotalBill,2))) 





print "The toatal number of Customer's who went over their minute's usage limit is... " ,TotalCust_ovrminute
print "The total number of Customer's who went over their texting limit is... " ,TotalCust_ovrtext
print "The total number of Customer's who went over their data limit is... " ,TotalCust_ovrdata
```

Some of the variables created are not used in the program.  Please overlook them.

Comment: Do the same thing. Accumulate the values for the sum of bills as you process each loop iteration.

Comment: @PreetSangha But how? (I'm a rookie)

Comment: @PreetSangha would I create another equation like "TotalBill"

Comment: Can anyone else help me.  No offense to Preet, I just need someone to give me an example.  if its not too much to ask

Comment: yes just create some meta totals.

Comment: Just initiate the relevant sums before your loop, append during the loop and print after the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Preet suggested.

create another variable like TotalBill i.e.

```
AccumulatedBill = 0
```

Then at the end of your loop put.

```
AccumulatedBill += TotalBill
```

This will add each TotalBill to Accumulated. Then simply print out the result at the end.

```
print "Total for all customers is: %s" %(AccumulatedBill)
```

Note: you don't normally use uppercase on variables for the first letter of the word. Use either camelCase or underscore_separated.